# How to read a file and simultaneously fill an array

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

In a C program I'm writing I have to read values from a text file and put them in an array for later use.

I don't like my code (snippet shown below) because I do two `while` loops, the first to count the number of values, then I create an array as big as that value, and lastly I read the file again, filling the array.

Also, in the first loop, I use a variable `x` because the `fscanf()` requires it, but I never use it later in the code and I'd like to avoid it at all if possible.

```
int x, n=0, sum=0;
fp=fopen("data.txt", "r");

while(fscanf(fp,"%d\n",&x)!=EOF){
    n++;
}

rewind(fp);
int v[n];

while(fscanf(fp,"%d\n",&v[i])!=EOF){
    sum+=v[i];
    i++;
}
```

So, any advice on how can I improve this code? I figured I could kinda "fix" it by declaring an array big "enough" at the beginning and filling it as needed. But I don't know in advance how many values I have to work with, so I decided to trash out this method.

Comment: You could implement an `std::vector`-like solution manually, enlarging the array as needed as you read elements from the file. Other than that, in C, I don't think you can do anything unless the numbers have constant width (always one/two etc digits, maybe?) - then you could precalculate the needed array size.

Comment: And BTW, if you want to ignore some value in your `scanf` format string, you can do this: `%*d` - then you don't need that `x`.

Comment: Note that your `fscanf` will return 0 (and not `EOF`) when the read characters aren't a valid number. In that case, the file pointer is rewound to the place before the `fscanf` and you end up trying to read the same input over and over, without success. A better approach might be `while (fscanf("%d", &v[i]) == 1)`, which stops at the first illegal input,  or a combined `fscanf("%s", ...)` and `strtol` approach, which allows better error handling.

Comment: Just thinking, a simple linked list would eliminate the first for-loop - however this wouldn't simplify the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one scenario where dynamic memory allocation can come handy. You can follow the general procedure as described below

1. Define a pointer.
2. Open the file [`fopen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) and read the first element from the file [`fscanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf). Error check should be taken care, also.
3. If the read is successful, allocate memory dynamically [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) to the pointer and copy the value.
4. Read next element.

   4.1. If the read is successful

   - If the read is successful, re-allocate the memory [`realloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) with one more new element size.
   - Copy the last read value to the newly allocated memory.

   4.2. If the read id failure, check for EOF and stop the reading.
5. Continue to step 4.

Also, please keep in mind, the memory which you have allocate using dynamic memory allocation, needs to be [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free)d also.

---

<sup>As a note, [referring to the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31381036/how-to-read-a-file-and-simultaneously-fill-an-array/31381155#comment50740135_31381155) of Mr. **@ szczurcio**, this is not an optimized effort, because, you've to re-allocte memory in each successful read. TO minimize the impact of dynamic memory allocation, we can decide on a threshold value which we will use to allocate memory and then, when exhausted, will double the amount of the previous value. This way, the allocation will happen in a chunk and the allocation overhead in each read cycle can be avoided.</sup>

Comment: IMO reallocating the memory after each read would be pretty wasteful - allocate twice as much as you had previously, like the STL does.

Comment: @szczurcio Yes, you're very right. I was just trying to provide the basic idea of dynamic memory allocation. If we propose the optimized way at the beginning itself, someone new to this may think, that is the way for any allocation, which , in general is not TRUE. hope I am clear. :-)

Comment: @szczurcio I have added a note to my answer, please let me know if that can be improved. :-)

Comment: @szczurcio You don't want to allocate twice as much either (for reasons to complex to fit into this comment). The optimal ratio is the golden proportion Φ = (1+sqrt 5)/2 = 1.61803.

Comment: This is an interesting concept, I will definitely study it a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Minor changes to the code, please note that I've changed v to be an int* and then check the amount of carriage returns in the file. I then allocate the correct amount of memory for the array, rewind file and then let your code loop through the file again...

```
int x, n=0, sum=0;
char c;
int* v;
int i = 0;

fp=fopen("data.txt", "r");


while (f.get(c))
    if (c == '\n')
        ++i;    

rewind(fp);

v = malloc( i * sizeof( int ));

i = 0;
while(fscanf(fp,"%d\n",&v[i])!=EOF)
{
    sum+=v[i];
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Hmm not the tidiest code, but it shows the point of allocating etc. With not knowing the amount of data in the file, it needs two loops, one to count, the other to fill the array.

Comment: There is no need to cast the result of `malloc()` & friends in C, nor is it recommened in any way to do so.

Comment: Thanks - wrote it in a hurry - removed cast. Whoops.

Comment: Also please note, that there not necessarily needs to be a final new-line. In this case the code would write beyond the memory allocated to `v`.

Comment: Also^2 `i` should be `size_t` not `int`.

Comment: I am beginning to regret posting this answer Alk  :-)   I'll update the answer... thanks.... :-)

Comment: I can't see how the code would over-write the bounds of the array. I feel the concept of how to improve on the original source has been answered. The source was never intended to be used as final release, the additions were done to the original and posted as an example, keeping in line with the original draft. I am not sure how helpful this is becoming.

Answer (score 0):

As said by Sourav, dynamic memory allocation is definitely the way to go.

That said, you can also change the data structure to another that doesn't require a priori knowledge of N. If you only need sequential access to the values and don't really need random access, a linked list is an option. Moreover, you can always use binary trees, hash tables and so on. Depends on what you want to do with the data.

P.S: srry, I'd post this as a comment, but I don't have the reputation.

Answer (score 0):

This is the typical scenario in which you would like to know the size of the file before creating the array. Well, better speaking, the number of lines in the file.

I'm going to suggest something radically different. Since this is a text file, the smallest number will occupy two chars (smallest in a "text" sense), one for the digit, and another one for the `\n` (though the `\n` can be one or two bytes, that's OS dependant).

We can now the size of the file. After `fopen`'ing it, you can, through `ftell`, know how many bytes it holds. If you divide that number by 2, you will have an approximation of the maximum possible number of lines in the file. So you can create the array of that size, and then save the number of positions really occupied.

```
FILE * fp = fopen( "data.txt", "rt" );

/* Get file size */
fseek( fp, SEEK_END, 0 );
long size = ftell( fp );
fseek( fp, SEEK_SET, 0 );

/* Create data */
long MaxNumbers = size / 2;
int * data = (int *) malloc( sizeof( int ) * MaxNumbers );
long lastPos = 0;

/* Read file */
int * next = data;
while( fscanf(fp, "%d\n", next) != EOF ) {
    ++next;
}

lastPos = ( next - data ) / sizeof( int );

/* Close the file */
fclose( fp );
```

Once you have the data loaded in `data`, you know the real number of items, so you can copy it to another array of the exact size (maybe through `memcpy()`), or stay with this array. If you want to change the array:

```
int * v = (int *) malloc( sizeof( int ) * lastPos );
memcpy( v, data, sizeof( int ) * lastPos );
free( data );
```

Note: this code is a simple demo, and it does not check for NULL's after calling `malloc()`, while a real program should.

This code does not waste memory or computation time when expanding the array because the data does not fit. However, it a) creates an array at the beginning which is potentially bigger than needed, and b) if you want to have an array of the exact size, then you will temporally have twice the needed space allocated. We are changing memory for better performance, and sometimes this is not a good idea for our environment (i.e., an embedded system).

A big improvement to this strategy would be to be able to deal with the input file. If you dedicate the same space to each number (say there are always three positions, and a 3 is stored as 003), and you know the maximum number (in order to know how many spaces you need for each number), then the algorithm will be completely accurate, and you don't need to change the data read to another array or whatever. With this change, this strategy is simply the best one I can imagine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is more complicated than I initially thought, but it's actually a good enough solution. I'm writing this code for statistical purposes, and since the values are measured they're all about the same. At least, they all have the same number of digits. Thanks.